How to protect already-installed pex pipes in shallow wall
I recently had a house repiped by a plumbing company.The main water line comes in from the outside through an exterior wall. This type of wall has 3/4" furring strips that go between the concrete block and the drywall.
I'm worried about someone unknowingly driving a screw through the PEX pipe, especially since:

The PEX pipe is basically touching the drywall, so it's very easy for almost any screw to penetrate
The PEX pipe is not protected by any type of conduit
The PEX pipe has very little room for movement since it's secured inside a notch within the furring strip

What are my options for protecting the water line in this situation?

Edit, after removing some of the expanding foam I noticed the pipe is protected inside the concrete block except for the very small section visible near the top of the ceiling, so it doesn't look too bad. I plan to put additional horizontal nail plates to try to protect as much or all of that run of the PEX pipe.


Get some sheet metal and glue it on top of the pipe. Or directly to drywall pieces when putting them back in. Make sure you have enough space, but you can always scratch a groove in the drywall. This will protect the pipe from being penetrated by a drill or a nail. Do educate yourself and others who would like to drill holes in your walls that metal plate = stop drilling.
For thickness, go with what's available. A strip 2 inches wide and 1/10 or 1/12 inch thick should be fine.

This is exactly what I was thinking. Luckily, the length of pipe running along the drywall turned out to be a only a small section, and most of it is running inside the concrete block.

At this point, take pictures and measure/document exactly where the water line is located for future reference. Also, make sure everyone in the house understands your concern and realizes what will happen if the pipe is punctured. I'm assuming you don't want warning signs on the wall or the pipe location drawn on the wall in red.
A better solution might have been to re route the main feed differently to avoid that wall but it's too late for that.

A nice accent stripe might work on the wall.  If like me reading notes/instructions after something does not work right.
